# Can Jenkins have streaming-output pipeline stages?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking for the proper solution platform to run several Java scripts,
before taking time into learning Jenkins,
I need someone to help me confirm **if my case can be performed in Jenkins**.

I will explain my case by the diagram below:

[image]

When the first stage **CSV Lines Parsing** is executed, this stage will read the CSV files.

Then, **for each CSV line**, this stage will consume each line and stream it to the next stage. (i.e., the following stages will be executed driven by every line)

Hence, while the first stage is consuming the CSV file, for each line, it triggers the next stage, but it doesn't end up, it's still consuming the next line of the file until the whole file consumed.

Could I make this in Jenkins? 
Any hints are appreciate. I need only the confirmation to whether my case can be fulfilled, therefore I will go learn it by any hints given :), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This use case can be handled by creating 2 different pipeline jobs in Jenkins

1. Parsing Pipeline - This will do the job of parsing. Instead of Jenkins, any other parsing solution can also be applied here
2. Filter/Build pipeline - This will do Filtering-Clone-Build-Logging stages

Parsing Pipeline can invoke Filter/Build pipeline and pass the parsed file as input parameter. Instead of Jenkins, any client utility or program can be used for parsing and this utility or program can invoke Jenkins REST APi to trigger Build pipeline. 
Please treat this as hint